# syntax error about SQLitedatabase ,When is select*from

Tags: android, syntax-error

This is error

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROMfriendsWHERE":
>   syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT*FROMfriendsWHERE id != ?

This is my code

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+FriendsDBHelper.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE id != ?",new String[]{Integer.toString(0)});
```

Comment: Looks like your spacing is not being applied to the string

Comment: Clean your project and run..

Comment: `!=`  is java , use `<>` instead..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+FriendsDBHelper.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE id NOT LIKE ?",new String[]{Integer.toString(0)});
```

`NOT LIKE` is used for `do not have ? value in it`

Or

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+FriendsDBHelper.TABLE_NAME+" WHERE id <> ?",new String[]{Integer.toString(0)});
```

`<>` is used for `is not equal to ?`

Comment: Did you meant to use `NOT IN` ?? B'coz, what you currently posted may not work